# reading the lines in file from specific position

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to read lines from  specific position from a txt file.
below is the output i have got

```
['Type : aa-aaaa-aaa']                    #output should not have this line
['consumed by bbbbbbbb : 0x0x0 WWWWW']    #output should not have this line
['Pppp CCCC TTTT                           MMMMM            SSSSSS Nonoo.']   #output should have this line
['']                                                                        #output should not have this line
['1  NIL fL-E 10UU (SPD+), 1000XXXXX (SPD) WEEEEEEEEEEEEE   CATTTTTTTTT']   #read the file from here
['44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT']
['44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT']
['44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT']
['44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT']
['44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT']  #till here
```

from the code i have tried: -

```
with open ('sh_mooooo.txt', 'r') as mooo_info:
    lines = moooo_info.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        if not l.isspace():
            storeSplit = [" ".join(l.split()[1:9])]
            print (storeSplit)
```

**Expected output: -**

```
Pppp CCCC TTTT                           MMMMM            SSSSSS Oono.   

1  NIL fL-E 10UU (SPD+), 1000XXXXX (SPD) WEEEEEEEEEEEEE   CATTTTTTTTT   
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
44 10/100/1000BBBBB Ppppppp OOo E SSSSSS WS-XXXXX-RRRRR+I CATTTTTTTTT
```

thx for the help.! :-)

Comment: what exactly is the criterion which lines to read and which not? If you mean position in the sense of index then see Adam.Er8 's answer

Comment: Could you also upload the original sh_mooooo.txt file..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use slicing.

replace `lines = moooo_info.readlines()` with this:

```py
lines = moooo_info.readlines()[2:]
```

it means "all except the first 2 element"

also, you seems like you wrap your strings a list with need.

try this:

```py
with open ('sh_mooooo.txt', 'r') as mooo_info:
    lines = moooo_info.read().splitlines()[2:]
    for l in lines:
        if not l.isspace():
            storeSplit = " ".join(l.split())
            print (storeSplit)
```

Comment: note: your expected output suggests you want to skip the first 2 lines, but your comments suggest you want to skip the first 4 lines. you can change the `2:` to `4:` as you need...

Comment: @Mystery OK, great, could you try my answer and tell me if it works?

Comment: your code somewhat works but it somehow deletes  **CATTTTTTTTT** from first line (where it appeared for the very first time) and also **read.splitlines()** throws error of **bulitin_function_or_method**

Comment: yes.! @Adam.Er8 it works fine now.! Also there would some more questions today.! (as new to python). thnx for the help.!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197250/discussion-between-mystery-and-adam-er8).